# Add UIImage to NSMutableArray through Delegate Method S3

Tags: iphone, iterator, amazon-s3, nsmutablearray, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get AWS S3 to go get images from an S3 bucket, the code below is in two parts. The first (I think) creates the get object request after initiating the array to put the object in (arrayImages, it gets the count from arrayPointer). The second is the delegate method that puts the object (data) in arrayImages once it finishes. I would assume that each time the delegate method is called it would add a new object. Something is wrong here:

```
-(void)gets3ImageArray
{

    if (arrayImages == nil) {
        arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[arrayPointer count]];
    }
    else
    {
        [arrayImages removeAllObjects];
    }

    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];

    for (NSString *name in arrayPointer){
            @try {
        S3GetObjectRequest *gor = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc]initWithKey:name withBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]];
        [gor setDelegate:self];
        [s3 getObject:gor];

    }

    @catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
        [Constants showAlertMessage:exception.message withTitle:@"Download Error"];
    }
    }
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    if(!myImage) 
    {
        NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
        [arrayImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
    [arrayImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}
```

Comment: if you call [self gets3ImageArray] multiple times its can never exceed the initial capacity you set. may want to check that. Is the delegate method actually return data that isKindOfClass UIImage? You already have myImage so just add that instead of creating another image from imageWithData. First check that an image is returned.

Comment: an image is returned, I get issues when there is more than one. I took out the initWithCapacity and still get crashes. The crashes tend to occur on larger images.

Comment: i'm not familiar with these delegate methods from Amazon, are there any more? it is likely that you are only using the first pass of returned data, not the entire stream. hence smaller files work.

Comment: How would I add a stream? I'm not familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append the data received in your ...

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

...method as it can be called multipled times. declare a NSMutableData *responseData in your header file and append the data until your didCompleteWithResponse delegate is called.

```
[responseData appendData:data];
```

Make sure you alloc the mutable data before you call the AmazonS3Client.

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; // or autorelease or not depending on ARC etc
```

You will likely need to implement all these delegates: (but the amazon docs should be able to confirm)

- didReceiveResponse: Sent when body data has been read. May be called multiple times.
- didReceiveData: Sent when body data has been read. May be called multiple times.
- didCompleteWithResponse: Sent when the entire response has been read and processed. The object sent to this method is the same object returned when making a non-asynchronous request.
- didSendData: Sent when the request transmitted data.
- didFailWithError: Sent when there was a basic failure with the underlying connection.
- didFailWithServiceException: Sent when the service responded with an error message.

Comment: How do I separate each call of didReceiveData to separate the images?

Comment: When didCompleteWithResponse is called your mutableData will be complete. Then check if image and use as before.

Comment: it appears to be treating all of the mutable data as the same data / last data loaded.

Comment: Make sure you set it to nil when the delegate first subsequent times ;-)

Comment: Sorry not familiar with this protocol. It would appear that way though.

Comment: most likely use [responseData setLength:0]; in your didReceiveResponse delegate.